# How to add apps that doesn't appear on dash home to launcher?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

Today I've spent all day trying to fix an Ubuntu 11.04 but I failed. I didn't wanted to upgrade one step further because I am trying to avoid Unity, but I had to recover that PC so I installed 11.10, now after a few hours I am not hating it so much, I kinda like it but I still don't quite understand some things.

For example, I found I was able to drag and drop apps from the dash home results to the left bar and they will get "sticked" there, but later I installed VirtualBox, which doesn't appear on dash home results (but if I type it on a console it does launch fine).

So how could I add VirtualBox to the left bar when I can't find it on dash home search results to drag and drop it? I don't just want to add the main VirtualBox to the bar, but also the virtual machines shortcut, like I use to do in previous Ubuntu versions by just adding an application launcher to the menu.

Comment: Refer to this - [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/a/78968/25798)

Answer (score 2):

The virtualbox icon will appear in the launcher on the side when you launch the application in Terminal, correct? If so, right-click the Virtualbox icon and click "Keep in Launcher".